# Trying to load a chart with chart.js, through ajax and php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js

I have created a php page where the graph works fine if loaded in the browser.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
 <div id="dashboard_pie_pop_cont"><canvas id="dashboard_graph_quantity_enquiries_salespeople"</canvas</div>
 <script>
        var enquiriesquantitysalespeople = {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    data: [6,1,],
                    backgroundColor: ["#2585fe", "#71b0ff", "#29bb52", "#497956", "#fcb858", "#f8cd90"],
                    borderWidth: 0,
                }],
                labels: ['Lee Davies','Lee Davies']
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'right',
                    textDirection: 'rtl',
                    labels: {
                        boxWidth: 14,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontColor: "#000",
                        fontFamily: 'proxima-nova',
                    }
                },
                animation: {
                    animateScale: true,
                    animateRotate: true
                }
                
            }
        };
    window.onload = function() {
        var enquiriesquantitysalespeople_chart = document.getElementById('dashboard_graph_quantity_enquiries_salespeople').getContext('2d');
        window.myDoughnut = new Chart(enquiriesquantitysalespeople_chart, enquiriesquantitysalespeople);};
   </script>
   <body></html>
```

So when this page is loaded it works fine. But if I call it through ajax. Then its just blank, and graph doesnt show.

Here is the ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    //dataType : 'json',
    url     : '//'+base_url+'/ajax2/dashboard-pie.php',
    success : function(data) {
        $('#dashboard_graph_pop_cont').html(data);
    }
});
```

And there is the container

```
        <div id="dashboard_graph_pop_cont">
            
        </div>
```

The container loads just fine if I replace the `data` variable some test text, e.g. `$('#dashboard_graph_pop_cont').html('test');` then 'test' would appear in the container. Meaning there is some reason the javascript wont run in ajax.

What am I doing wrong?

The console log retunrs

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>

</head>


    <body>
   <div id="dashboard_pie_pop_cont"><canvas id="dashboard_graph_quantity_enquiries_salespeople"></canvas></div>
      <script>
        
         var enquiriesquantitysalespeople = {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    data: [6,1,],
                    backgroundColor: ["#2585fe", "#71b0ff", "#29bb52", "#497956", "#fcb858", "#f8cd90"],
                    borderWidth: 0,
                }],
                labels: ['Lee Davies','Lee Davies']
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'right',
                    textDirection: 'rtl',
                    labels: {
                        boxWidth: 14,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontColor: "#000",
                        fontFamily: 'proxima-nova',
                    }
                },
                animation: {
                    animateScale: true,
                    animateRotate: true
                }
                
            }
        };window.onload = function() {
        var enquiriesquantitysalespeople_chart = document.getElementById('dashboard_graph_quantity_enquiries_salespeople').getContext('2d');
        window.myDoughnut = new Chart(enquiriesquantitysalespeople_chart, enquiriesquantitysalespeople);};</script><body></html> scripts.js:4054:12
```

​

**EDIT**

Here's how we are calling AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    url     : '//'+base_url+'/ajax2/dashboard-pie.php',
    data    : 'col_action='+col_action+'&type='+type+'&chart='+chart,
    success : function(data) {
        console.log("data", data);
        $('#dashboard_graph_pop_cont').append('<div id="dashboard_pie_pop_cont" style="width: 100%; height: 100px"></div>');
        $('#dashboard_pie_pop_cont')
            .empty()
            .append(
            $('<canvas/>', {
                id: 'dashboard_graph_quantity_enquiries_salespeople'
            })
        );
                
    var enquiriesquantitysalespeople_chart = document.getElementById('dashboard_graph_quantity_enquiries_salespeople').getContext('2d');
    window.myDoughnut = new Chart(enquiriesquantitysalespeople_chart, data);            
    }
});
```

And dashboard-pie.php has:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

$data = [
  'type' => 'doughnut',
  'data' => [
    'datasets'=> [[
      'data'=> [6, 1],
      'backgroundColor' => ["#2585fe", "#71b0ff", "#29bb52", "#497956", "#fcb858", "#f8cd90"],
      'borderWidth'=> 0,
    ]],
    'labels'=> ['Lee Davies','Lee Davies']
  ],
  'options'=> [
    'responsive'=> true,
    'legend'=> [
      'position'=> 'right',
      'textDirection'=> 'rtl',
      'labels'=> [
        'boxWidth'=> 14,
        'fontSize'=> 14,
        'fontColor'=> "#000",
        'fontFamily'=> 'proxima-nova',
      ]
    ],
    'animation'=> [
      'animateScale'=> true,
      'animateRotate'=> true
    ]
  ]
];

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: You mention vars in your ajax code that you dont seem to show in your question? Can you show those var declarations since your ajax code depends on them? ... Also could you show `dashboard-pie.php`?

Comment: On "success" handler of ajax, which is really basically, the server has been reached, can you also `console.log()` the `data` response? Preferably before doing in thing else in that block.

Comment: The vars in question in my first comment which seem to have no mention (in terms of what they are) in your current unedited question include: `base_url`, `col_action`, `type`, `chart`.

Comment: @GetSet sorry, I am just using static values now, for testing purposes, vars removed.

Comment: Ok. But can you also and very needed `console.log(data)` on "success" and append that to your question? Also could you include the source code for `dashboard-pie.php` as it may be relevant on debugging since its called by the ajax?

Comment: I can only conclude you dont want help. Your "update" doesnt take heed to my requests As such, I dont know why you cant post the php code. And the console.log. Impossible to debug without it

Comment: With your rep, i dont really understand how you dont know what closed for lack of debugging details mean?

Comment: @GetSet sorry, sorry. I added `console.log(data)` into success, but I dont know what you wanted after that. I showed what it returned, in the edited OP.

Comment: I think issue is here `window.onload = function() {..` your graph is initialize on load of page so now you are just appending that inside your `Dom` .

Comment: @Swati thanks I think you might be right too, so how do I sort that?

Comment: you just need to load that php page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how jQuery [`html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) is intended to be used. You are not supposed to load entire HTML pages **including scripts** using [`html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method; it's a big security issue and that's why most likely is not going to work that way.

Instead, you should load all the libraries needed to the main page and fetch using AJAX, **ONLY** the data needed for the chart. Then use that data to generate/draw/append the chart inside your page.

#### For example using your code:

```js
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : `//${base_url}/ajax2/dashboard-pie-json-data.php`,
    success : function(data) {
        var enquiriesquantitysalespeople = data;
        // Return just the data needed for the chart using JSON.
        // For example, enquiriesquantitysalespeople should contain data such as:
        // {
        //    type: 'doughnut',
        //    data: {
        //        datasets: [{...}],
        //        labels: ['Lee Davies','Lee Davies']
        //    },
        //    options: {
        //        responsive: true,
        //        ...
        //    }
        //    ...
        // }

        // Then get the 2D context of element you want to render the chart
        var enquiriesquantitysalespeople_chart = document
            .getElementById('dashboard_graph_quantity_enquiries_salespeople')
            .getContext('2d');

        // And create the chart using the data you just fetched to the 2D context
        window.myDoughnut = new Chart(
            enquiriesquantitysalespeople_chart,
            enquiriesquantitysalespeople
        );
    }
});
```

#### Sample Data return using PHP

```php
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

$data = [
  'type' => 'doughnut',
  'data' => [
    'datasets'=> [[
      'data'=> [6, 1],
      'backgroundColor' => ["#2585fe", "#71b0ff", "#29bb52", "#497956", "#fcb858", "#f8cd90"],
      'borderWidth'=> 0,
    ]],
    'labels'=> ['Lee Davies','Lee Davies']
  ],
  'options'=> [
    'responsive'=> true,
    'legend'=> [
      'position'=> 'right',
      'textDirection'=> 'rtl',
      'labels'=> [
        'boxWidth'=> 14,
        'fontSize'=> 14,
        'fontColor'=> "#000",
        'fontFamily'=> 'proxima-nova',
      ]
    ],
    'animation'=> [
      'animateScale'=> true,
      'animateRotate'=> true
    ]
  ]
];

echo json_encode($data);
```

This code snippet will make the AJAX request and dynamically create the canvas element each time the AJAX call finishes after we hit the load button.

*Run it to see it in action:*

```js
document.getElementById('load').addEventListener('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    url: 'https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/65660138/data.php',
    success : function(data) {
      // console.log('Got AJAX data', data);
      $('#dashboard_pie_pop_cont')
        .empty()
        .append(
          $('<canvas/>', {
            id: 'dashboard_graph_quantity_enquiries_salespeople'
          })
        );

      var enquiriesquantitysalespeople_chart = 
        document
          .getElementById('dashboard_graph_quantity_enquiries_salespeople')
          .getContext('2d');

      window.myDoughnut = new Chart(
        enquiriesquantitysalespeople_chart,
        data
      );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>

<button id="load">Load AJAX Chart</button>
<div id="dashboard_pie_pop_cont" style="width: 100%; height: 100px"></div>
```

#### iFrame solution

Also, an other option is to load the chart page inside an **iFrame** and not make an AJAX call at all.

Comment: Christos Lytras, I tried above technique to draw the chart but don't know why the chart is still not drawn after ajax response.

Comment: Is there any special method or chart.js API needed to draw or update chart via ajax?

Comment: No there is not. I have a mistake in the code, I get the `dashboard_graph_pop_cont` 2D context instead of the canvas `dashboard_graph_quantity_enquiries_salespeople`. I have corrected that. Also check the element's style that the chart is for to draw in, if it's visible and has width and height. Remember to include `css/layout.css` as well.

Comment: @Sachin thanks for the bounty. I suspect you resolved the issue, thus it would be nice to mark the answer as **accepted** so it will help developers having similar issues in the future.

Comment: sorry, still not able to get it working right.

Comment: @Sachin I can help you get it working right. What issues are you facing?

Comment: even my static data is not rendering in the chart

Comment: Do you have a git repo? Or even an uploaded and public site on a domain? Or a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that will try to fetch the PHP file from a server? If you don't, you can create a GitHub repository and commit your code there, if of course your code is not proprietary and you don't have sensitive data like API keys or passwords saved.

Comment: I can put the stuff on my server and then show you

Comment: @Sachin Yes, it would be nice to see it and see what you're doing wrong. I have setup your code as an example with 2 pages, one for plain view [here](https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/65660138/chart.php) (*without AJAX*) and one with a button that loads the data using AJAX [here](https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/65660138/ajax.php). Check if these are working for you and I will try to see your code later. I guess you're not returning the correct data from the PHP; it has to have a `Content-type: application/json` header for it to work; I have updated my answer to include a PHP data return example.

Comment: Actually, we don't have `<canvas id="dashboard_graph_quantity_enquiries_salespeople">` when AJAX response comes from server. So I am adding canvas before response using `$('#dashboard_graph_pop').html('<canvas id="dashboard_graph_quantity_enquiries_salespeople">')` but still no luck. I also gave 100% width and height to this canvas.

Comment: @Sachin that is not ideal (*using `html` to add new elements*); if you want to create the canvas element each time, then you should use `empty()` and `append()` to clean `dashboard_pie_pop_cont` and create/append the canvas inside it. Then use the code to create the chart. I have updated the answer with a working code snippet that does exactly that. Run it and press the *"Load AJAX Chart"* button to see it in action.

Comment: I tried your solution but still couldn't get it working right. I updated question and added the code snippet that is currently being used. Also the PHP sample data that you used must need to be format like that?

Comment: @Sachin Unfortunately I cannot accept that edit. You can't edit someone else's question to add your own code in order for others to view and debug. Either upload your code to a public repository (*like a GitHub repo*) or create a [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/) that will fetch the data from your server. And yes, this is how we write data in PHP, using keyed arrays that will then be converted to JSON.

Comment: Ok I will try to upload stuff to somewhere else. Yes I know how to construct named index array data in PHP but I meant to ask was that can't we put whole chart.js code (`'type' => 'doughnut' ... 'animation'...` in a single key? This is how we get data in our code flow.